# Do .htaccess statements "require host..." relate to actual clients and/or to cross-origin servers, hosting some static front_end?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fetch, cross-domain

Lets say I have

**a)** some *back_end* API running at `foo.com`

**b)** some static *front_end* based on JavaScript, provided at `baa.com`, calling API from `foo.com` with fetch requests

**c)** some special *client* C with ip `xy`

**d)** some other clients.

I would like to create some `.htaccess` file(s), always allowing the *front_end* at `baa.com` to call the *back_end* API. I would like to be able to specify what clients are allowed to see the results. The clients should for example not be allowed to use the *back_end* API directly but only via `baa.com`.

=> From the perspective of `foo.com`: where do the requests come from?

Is the origin of the request always the *client*, because the JavaScript fetch command is executed in the browser of the client? Or is `baa.com` the origin? Or is there a way to distinguish both "origins"? Does `.htaccess` of `foo.com` "know", that the *front_end* has been served by `baa.com` and the *client* request comes from ip `xy`?

Example content for `.htaccess` file at `foo.com`:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/www/users/foo/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic


Require valid-user
Require host foo.com  # <= host of client or host of cross-orgin front_end ?
Require ip xy
```

Related:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: The _origin_ (as HTTP defines the term) of the request is `baa.com`, because that is where your JS code is executing. But the origin of the request, is not the same as the one _making_ the request - `host` in this instance would be the client machine, that this request is made from.

Comment: _"Does .htaccess of foo.com "know", that the front_end has been served by baa.com"_ - it would see `baa.com` in the referrer (if any was send), and also in the `Origin` header - which the client will set, because this is a cross-origin request. _"The clients should for example not be allowed to use the back_end API directly but only via baa.com."_ - you can enforce that for client-side code that adheres to CORS restrictions; but nothing would stop me from making the request using _any_ HTTP client of my choosing, and simply setting the `Origin` header myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped my to understand it better.

Answer (score -1):

With the help of the comments from CBroe and some KI I found the answers below. If I understand it correctly, I cannot really ensure, that only requests referred by baa.com are allowed at foo.com.

**A.** In the context of the `.htaccess` file on foo.com, some `Require host example.com` statement refers to the host of the client making the request to foo.com. The host, in this case, pertains to the domain of the client's IP address or the domain of the client's DNS resolution.

The front-end, which is hosted on baa.com, is not directly related to this `Require host` statement in the `.htaccess` file on foo.com. The statement is focused on the source of the request, which is the client accessing foo.com.

So, some `Require host example.com` directive in the `.htaccess` file on foo.com ensures that only requests originating from the host/domain example.com are allowed to access the resources on foo.com.

**B.** To ensure that only requests referred from baa.com are allowed at foo.com, you can implement a combination of techniques to enhance the security and integrity of your application.

1. Referer Header Check: While the `Referer` header can be faked, you can still perform a basic check to verify that the request is coming from baa.com. In your server-side code on foo.com, check the `Referer` header value and compare it with the expected value of `https://baa.com`. If they match, allow the request to proceed; otherwise, reject or handle it accordingly.
2. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS): Implement CORS on foo.com's server-side to control which domains are allowed to make requests to the API. Configure the server to only allow requests from baa.com using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This provides an additional layer of security and ensures that only requests originating from baa.com are allowed. However, the 'Origin' header can be faked, too.
3. Authentication and Authorization: Implement a robust authentication and authorization mechanism on foo.com. This can involve user authentication, session management, and role-based access control. By requiring users to authenticate themselves, you can ensure that only authorized users can access the resources on foo.com, regardless of the referrer.
4. Secure Communication: Make sure that the communication between the client (browser) and foo.com (API) is done over a secure connection using HTTPS. This helps protect against potential network eavesdropping and ensures the integrity of the requests.

By combining these techniques, you can enhance the security of your application and minimize the risk of unauthorized access to foo.com's API. However, it's important to note that determined attackers can still find ways to bypass these measures, so it's always recommended to have additional security measures and monitoring in place.

**To B. 1.**

The `Referer` header provides information about the referring URL that led the client to make the request. You can check the `Referer` header value in the `.htaccess` file to verify if the request is coming from baa.com.

Here's an example of how you can use the `Referer` header in the `.htaccess` file to allow requests referred from baa.com:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://baa.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

In this example, the `RewriteCond` directive checks if the `HTTP_REFERER` variable (which contains the `Referer` header value) does not start with `https?://baa.com`. The `NC` flag makes the comparison case-insensitive.

The `RewriteRule` with `[F]` flag is used to return a 403 Forbidden status code and block access to any request that does not meet the condition.

By including this code in the `.htaccess` file on foo.com, only requests that have baa.com as the referring URL will be allowed to access the resources on foo.com. Requests from any other referring URL will be blocked.

It is possible for clients to fake the `Referer` header in their requests. The `Referer` header is part of the HTTP request and can be modified or even omitted by the client.

Clients can use various methods or tools to modify the `Referer` header, including browser extensions, custom scripts, or sending requests directly using tools like cURL or Postman. This means that relying solely on the `Referer` header for security or access control purposes is not completely reliable.

**To B. 2.**
The `Origin` header, which is used in Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), can potentially be faked by an attacker. The `Origin` header is set by the client's browser and can be modified or manipulated by the client.

An attacker could potentially modify the `Origin` header in their request to make it appear as if it is coming from baa.com, even if it is not. This is known as a cross-origin request forgery (CSRF) attack.

To mitigate the risk of CSRF attacks, it is recommended to combine the use of the `Origin` header with other security measures such as:

1. Proper authentication and session management: Implement a robust authentication mechanism and ensure that each request includes a valid session token or other authentication credentials.
2. CSRF tokens: Generate and include CSRF tokens in your forms or API requests. These tokens should be unique per session and validated on the server-side to ensure the request is legitimate.
3. Same-Site cookies: Set the `SameSite` attribute on cookies to prevent them from being sent in cross-site requests. This helps protect against CSRF attacks that rely on cookie-based authentication.

By implementing these additional security measures, you can enhance the protection against CSRF attacks and ensure that only legitimate requests from baa.com are allowed at foo.com.